# How can I fix these layout problems?

Tags: css, templates, html

I am stuck with some things, I need help to get:

a) to get the banner to the top of the page

b) to get the menu bar to the middle of the page underneath the banner

c) to put my image in the content area (it won't show up!)

***Edited!!***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page 1</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
body{
margin: 0;

}
#banner > h1{ 
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background-size: 1200px 300px;
text-align: center;
font-family: verdana; sans-serif;
color: #000000;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: bold;
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #596A72 0%, #FFFCFA 50%, #596A72 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #596A72 0%, #FFFCFA 50%, #596A72 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #596A72 0%, #FFFCFA 50%, #596A72 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #596A72), color-stop(50, #FFFCFA), color-stop(100, #596A72));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #596A72 0%, #FFFCFA 50%, #596A72 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #596A72 0%, #FFFCFA 50%, #596A72 100%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

#menu {
margin: 0;
top: 150px;
width: 400px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #336699;
float: center;
font-family: verdana; sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;

}

li {
float: left;
}

a {
display: block;
width: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#content {
background-image: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
margin-left: 203px;
left: 100px;
width: 1050px;
height: 1000px;

}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="banner">
<h1>
    TITLE
</h1>
</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="content">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At the least, you need `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` on the menu css.  As far as the image, not sure why it wouldn't appear as long as its not nested in a wierd div.
https://jsfiddle.net/fyc71qw5/

Comment: there are a few typos, such as extra `</a>` and the wrong syntax for `font-family`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the the closing quotemarks to the `<div id="content"></div>`

3) This should work:

```
#content {
background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
width: 1050px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work still. I've already corrected the quotation marks.

Comment: @sarangheh510 here is working copy [https://jsfiddle.net/hmdvrxpo/](https://jsfiddle.net/hmdvrxpo/) 
Also check your image source.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#banner > h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

2)

```
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

3) You have to include `<div id="content"></div>` to your HTML and change `background-image` to `background` in your CSS.

Comment: The first part worked for A), but B) and C) don't work. The image still won't show up.

Comment: 2) It is working. 3) change `<div id="content></div>` to `<div id="content"></div>` and `background-image` to `background`

Comment: that did nothing haha. And b) I want it at the center of the entire page.